# Is there a way to find common formula for similar polynominals

Tags: polynomials

I'm trying to find a common formula for all the curves found in the attached chart. Is this possible at all

[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5xvj.jpg)

For instance, I have the first line, let's ignore the scale of the chart and use it as a grid, it has the following points:

- P1 = x = 0 y = 90
- P2 = x = 10 y = 102
- P3 = x = 20 y = 112
- P4 = x = 30 y = 119.5
- P5 = x = 40 y = 124.5
- P6 = x = 50 y = 128.5
- P7 = x = 60 y = 130.5
- P8 = x = 65 y = 131

Then there's another line, further up the chart, with the following points:

- P1 = x = 0 y = 160
- P2 = x = 10 y = 176
- P2 = x = 10 y = 102
- P3 = x = 20 y = 189.5
- P4 = x = 30 y = 199.5
- P5 = x = 40 y = 207
- P6 = x = 50 y = 212
- P7 = x = 60 y = 215
- P8 = x = 65 y = 215.5

Is it possible to find the formula and apply it anywhere on the chart? I would appreciate your guidance and patience as I'm coming from a humanities education.

Comment: Do we even know that the curves are the results of polynomials?

Comment: What I would do, is to read the book around the graph and see if there is any algebraic derivation for the graphs. Maybe it's some specific expression ...

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should choose your tags carefully. What has this to do with `linear-algebra`?

Comment: In general, if you only have a finite number of points of a graph, you cannot "guess" the exact algebraic expression that they came from. But in practise, you might get lucky or get only small errors.

Comment: @MattiP. Unfortunately there is no algebraic derivation mentioned in the book.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos sorry, I fixed to the best of my ability to name it